# is there a way to get hold on all three child's app pipes that is STDOUT, STDIN and STDERR in MinGW?

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw, pipe

I can't find a working example anywhere. MinGW has `_popen()` but they say it is implemented through windows API, so it should be possible. But all examples I am able to find are for VisualC++ or some other newer langs like C# etc.

For example I try to make a wrapper for another program that would display all stderr in red color.

Comment: Visual C++ code (not the C++/CLI or .Net stuff) will work with MinGW if all it does is call Win32 API functions.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `popen` is not good enough, you have to use [`pipe`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) to create the file handles, [`fork`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) to create a new process, [`close`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close) to close the old `FILENO_STDIN`/`FILENO_STDOUT` in the child process, and [`dup2`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) to duplicate the pipes to the new `FILENO_STDIN`/`FILENO_STDOUT`, and last one of the [`exec`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) function to start the new program.

In other words, you basically have to reimplement the `popen` function.

It is also very common, and there are plenty of examples on the Internet.

Comment: I have fork and pipe on windows in MinGW ?

Comment: @rsk82 MinGW should have an almost full set of POSIX system calls. Or you can go the pure WIN32-way too, as commented by rubenvb.

Comment: Yes, I can go pure win32, but I do not know how, those examples on msdn do not work. - I found also that: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.mingw.user/28505/